# Getting last updated on a table as a dbowner

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, smo

I need to get a last updated timestamp when for a table. This operation is to be performed by a dbowner, who has GRANT EXEC permissions on all sprocs. Any ideas how to accomplish this? Here is what I tried.

I tried getting this info using SMO, but because of the lack of permissions it returns a null table object.

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
   ServerConnection serverConnection = new ServerConnection(connection);
   Server server = new Server(serverConnection);
   Database database = server.Databases["MyDb"];
   Table table = database.Tables["MyTable"];    // here table is null for dbowner user, but a valid object for a super user
   DateTime lastModified = table.DateLastModified;
}
```

Also tried creating a new sproc, but when I call it I get `The user does not have permission to perform this action.`

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getTableLastModifiedDate
    (
        @TableName nvarchar(max)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT last_user_update FROM sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats 
    WHERE OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)=@TableName AND database_id = DB_ID(DB_NAME())
END
GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the help topic for [`sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188755.aspx):

> Requires VIEW SERVER STATE permission.

If you look at the [server permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186717.aspx): `VIEW SERVER STATE` is implied by `ALTER SERVER STATE` in turn implied by `CONTROL SERVER`. System administrators have the required permissions, database administrators do not.

The best solution is to sign the procedure and then grant the required permission through the signature, see [Signing an activated procedure](http://rusanu.com/2006/03/01/signing-an-activated-procedure/) for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It seems to me that your proposed solution is too complicated for a simple question of "when was the table last modified." Is there a simpler solution of extracting this piece of data?